# pinterest like grid using ember

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create pinterest like grid for my web app. I guess on mobile devices it should show two columns and more on large devices.

I have tried using ember-collection but for that i need to know the height of the cards(i need to show cards in the grid) which is not possible for me. I tried using bootstrap after that. Below is my code with bootstrap but it is rendering single column only

```
<div class="row">
  {{#each model as |item|}}
    {{#feed-small class="col-md-2" feed=item}} {{/pixyfi-feed-small}}
    {{/each}}
 </div>
```

[image]
Could you please let me know where i am doing mistake?

**Update:**
using xs instead of md works but it leaves large vertical gaps

[image]

Comment: `md` classes are created for medium devices (min 768px). For mobile you should use xs size

Comment: using xs works but it leaves large verticle gaps as well. see updated post

Comment: what is your version of bootstrap?

Comment: I am using   "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",

Comment: could you create a snippet with the code you tried?

Comment: sure i'll do and will let u know

Comment: js fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/fs8Lh6md/. It might load a little slow as i have included all css generated by ember